# css transition property not working on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to apply css transition property when i hover the blocks.But its not working.Here's the code

```css
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 25px;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  left: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="service">
          Services
        </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Service1</a>
    <a href="#">Service2</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Is it because of the dropdown I have added or am i missing something?I am new to this field.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you applied transition on the wrong element and you need to set intial value like `left:0`

Answer (score 0):

this not possible for display in your code

you can translation for **Opacity** , **width** , **height** , background-color , ...

```css
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 25px;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: inline-grid;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  Opacity:0;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  left: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   transition:all 1s ease;
  Opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="service">
          Services
        </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Service1</a>
    <a href="#">Service2</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vu5kh3zn/)

[More information](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)